# Connect two or more iOS app to Apple Watch on WatchOS 2.0 version

Tags: ios, connection, apple-watch, watchos-2

With WatchOS 2 it is possible to connect more iOS apps to one WatchOS App? 
I have two my apps on device, and when i started one of them, i would receive more information of this on my watchOS app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apple Watch: Can one Watchkit App communicate with more than one iOS App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058805/apple-watch-can-one-watchkit-app-communicate-with-more-than-one-ios-app)

Comment: you can find your answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058805/apple-watch-can-one-watchkit-app-communicate-with-more-than-one-ios-app

Comment: But this answer it is old.. My question is for new WatchOS 2.0 , not 1.0